# Retaining a textbox values after a user checks and unchecks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Friends
In my application , I have a text box labelled as main content and there are two checkboxes  SMS and Email on top of it , 
Now I select the SMS checkbox , the textarea labelled as main content changes to SMS content and I could enter contents , how what is happening is 
**After a user selects SMS and types in SMS content text box and again deselects a checkbox SMS the SMS contents goes off , disappers** 
Instead it should stay as it is irrespective of user selects or deselects a checkbox.

My code for it is

```
if('SMS' === checkedValue){
         $("[data-main-content-for=Email]").find('textarea').val('');
                    }
```

**Please suggest a way to retain values after a user deselect and select checkbox again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling it instead of removing it

`$("[data-main-content-for=Email]").find('textarea').prop('disabled', true);`

Of course you will need to enable it again if they check the checkbox.

Comment: It disabled entire text area , which shouldnt happen

Answer (score 1):

`.val('')` will remove content of `textrea`

You have pasted email part of `js code`, You may also have SMS code something like this

`$("[data-main-content-for=SMS]").find('textarea').val('');`

If yes then you need to remove it to fix the issue

Comment: It doesnt work , It doent retain text , I need to retain the text on click of uncheck and check again

Comment: Please add relevant JS / HTML code in OP or create a jsFiddle